# Install perl module from rpm file

Tags: perl, rpm, pid

I have a perl issue and obviously I'm not a perl expert. I can not use CPAN.

I've installed File::Pid using a rpm, or I tried. I downloaded perl-File-Pid-1.01-3.el5.noarch.rpm (and the perl-Class-Accessor dependency) and installed using rpm -r XXX.rpm. I see the rpm installed.

I'm trying perl -MFile::Pid -e 1 and I see not installed the perl module.. Is there any procedure to install a perl module from rpm? I googling and I didn't find it yet.

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like you're using a different `perl` than the system perl. What do you get if you type `which perl` ?

Comment: What you did is correct, AFAICS. What does `rpm -q perl-File-Pid` say?

Comment: `rpm -ql perl-File-Pid` will show where the files were installed, showing the perl version it was installed for (as friedo notes above). `perl -V` will tell you where `perl` was looking for the modules.